# Replace empty entries with NA within a vector

Tags: r, na

I would like to replace all occurrences of `""` in a vector with `<NA>`. Suppose,

```
 V<- c("","Axe","Saw","")
```

Then after replacement,

```
  V<- c("<NA>","Axe","Saw","<NA>")
```

Using `gsub` to replace a substring is easy but for searching `""` I think I need to use `/` or `\` inside `""` but not sure how do do it.

Comment: If you want to replace the empty strings  by `NA`, you could do `V[V==''] <- NA`.  I don't see the point in replacing by a character NA. ie. `"<NA>"`  Suppose your `V` is `V <- c('""', 'Axe', 'Saw', '""');  gsub("[\"]+", "<NA>", V)`

Comment: Never thought about it. Thanks.

Comment: If your vector in fact happens to be derived from a data frame, and the `""` appeared upon reading this data to R, you may also have a look at the `na.strings` argument in the `read.table/csv/xyz` functions.

Answer (score 4):

You can use

```
is.na(V) <- V == ""
```

to replace empty strings with `NA`.

Answer (score 4):

There is a function named after exactly what you are trying to do: `replace()`.

With it, you can do:

```
> V<- c("","Axe","Saw","")
> V
[1] ""    "Axe" "Saw" ""   
> replace(V, V == "", NA)
[1] NA    "Axe" "Saw" NA
```

That's like saying "replace in the vector 'V' any values equal to '""' with NA". So, it's not a word-for-word transcription of your question title, but it is pretty close :-)